# Jquery Checkbox limit with a value that equals to the sum of 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, opencart

Ok, I have a jQuery that limits the amount of checkboxes that can be selected at one time. My problem is: I have 10 Checkboxes that have a value of 1. I also have 5 checkboxes that have a Value of 2. In Opecart, A product has a specific Value, so I cannot overwrite this value without breaking the system in place.

These 2 sets of checkboxes have there own limits assigned to them: Value 1 boxes have a limit of 5. Value 2 boxes have a limit of 2.

The sum they all add up to is 5. Is there any way of pairing these limitations up?

An Example of what I'm after: 
A User checks 3 Value 1 Checkboxes, the current value is 3. They can now, select 2 more value 1 checkboxes OR 1 value 2 checkbox to meet the sum of 5.

The Logic:

- 5 Value 1 = 5
- 3 Value 1 + 1 Value 2 = 5
- 1 Value 1 + 2 Value 2 = 5

This is the Jquery used to limit the checkboxes

```
var limit = 5;
$('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
   if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
       this.checked = false;
   }
});
```

This is an extract of the product page, where Opencart defines its own default value in the checkbox.

```
input class="limit" type="checkbox" name="option[547][]" value="1218" id="option-value-1218">
```

You can see I cannot just replace this value as it serves a purpose in the fact it pulls that products from the page to the cart. I need to find a way of applying the logic I have stated without compromising the system.

Answer (score 0):

Every time user change the check-box, you need to check the `summation` of `checked` values using `each()`

```
var limit = 5;
$('.limit').on('change', function(evt) {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.limit:checked').each(function(){
     sum += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  if(sum >= limit) {
       this.checked = false;
  }
});
```

FYI, if you can't change the values of check-boxes, you can use [**.data()**](https://api.jquery.com/data/) like `data-value` for additional attributes.

```js
var limit = 5;
$('.limit').on('change', function(evt) {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.limit:checked').each(function(){
     sum += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  if(sum > limit) {
     this.checked = false;
  }
});

FYI, if you can't change the value of check-boxes you can use **[.data()]**[1] like `data-value` for additional attributes.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="limit" type="checkbox" value="5"/>5
<input class="limit" type="checkbox" value="4"/>4
<input class="limit" type="checkbox" value="3"/>3
<input class="limit" type="checkbox" value="2"/>2
<input class="limit" type="checkbox" value="1"/>1
```

Comment: I have tried this, but as I stated in my question: Opencart have Default values for the products listed on the checkboxes. I cannot remove these values as they pull information from that specific product to the cart page: showing price, title, desc, etc. This would work if I wasn't using Opencart.

Comment: As your question say you want to limit the sum of checked boxes should be 5. It should not allow other to check.. So this way you can achieve the same. just change your values.

Comment: So If you cannot replace value of the check box with your custom data, try setting an attribute to the checkbox something like


input class="limit" type="checkbox" name="option[547][]" value="1218" id="option-value-1218" data-value="4">

Comment: So how would I apply this? I tried your method, Loading.. however my checkboxes are now uncheckable. I have assigned a data-value of 1 to my first set of checkboxes and

Comment: used Loading..'s set of Jquery but my checkboxes won't check when